# Segmentation fault when passing std::shared_ptr to subclass

Tags: c++, class, c++14, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

The following code illustrates my intent: https://godbolt.org/z/dhhascnoo

```cpp
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

class Dbg
{
protected:
    bool enabled;
public:
    Dbg() : enabled(false) {}
    Dbg(bool enable) : enabled(enable) {}

    void print() 
    {
        if (enabled) {
            std::cout << "Debugging!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

class C1
{
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<Dbg> dbg;
public:
    C1() { dbg = std::make_shared<Dbg>(false); }
    C1(std::shared_ptr<Dbg> dbg) : dbg(dbg) {}

    void print() 
    {
        dbg->print();
    }
};

class C0
{
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<Dbg> dbg;
    C1 c1Inst;
public:
    C0() : c1Inst(dbg) { dbg = std::make_shared<Dbg>(false); }
    C0(std::shared_ptr<Dbg> dbg) : dbg(dbg) {}

    void run()
    {
        c1Inst.print();
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Dbg> dbg = std::make_shared<Dbg>(true);

    C0 c0Inst;
    c0Inst.run();
}
```

Basically, I have some utility class that I want to pass to most of my objects that I run. With the ability to print out log messages (with configurable files to log them to).

I intend to pass a shared_ptr of this utility object to all of my subclasses. However, something about how I'm initiating the constructors to these classes seems to be off and causing a segfault.

I'm not as intimately knowledgeable about constructor design, so maybe someone can spot my mistake here?

---

**EDIT**: I realized my mistake here was not passing the actual pointer of `dbg` in main (doh!). It should be:

```cpp
int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<Dbg> dbg = std::make_shared<Dbg>(true);

  C0 c0Inst(dbg);
  c0Inst.run();
}
```

Still, the default constructor of `C0` should've created a new Dbg object to reference, no?

Comment: In C0() constructor the initializer c1Inst(dbg) is executed before the body of the constructor, so you pass NULL to c1Inst here.

Comment: Initalizer lists get called before constructor. `C0(): c1Inst(dbg) {dbg=std::...` looks like you first pass a dbg pointer to C1Inst and after that initialize dbg with variable

Answer (score 4):

Your code has [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) due to calling the unitized `std::shared_ptr<Dbg>`.

In class `C0`, you have not initialized the member `C1 c1Inst;` in its default constructor (i.e. `C0():...`) . Then you are calling the `run()` from the class

```
void run() {
    c1Inst.print();
}
```

Which will run the `print` from the `C1` where you have not initialized again the `std::shared_ptr<Dbg> dbg;`. This is undefined behavior.

---

In order to fix, you need simply the the constrictors of the `C0` be

```
C0()
    : dbg{ std::make_shared<Dbg>(false) }
    , c1Inst{ dbg }
{}

C0(std::shared_ptr<Dbg> dbg)
    : dbg(dbg)
    , c1Inst{ dbg }
{}
```

So-that all the members of the class will be initialized properly before using it. Here is [a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v3fKTnPh7)

Answer (score 0):

As it was said, you pass nullptr to C1, as initializer lists get called before constructor:
`C0(): c1Inst(dbg) {dbg=std::...` so you basically not initialized pointer for C1.

To solve it, you should initialize a pointer first, so for example change default constructor to:

```
C0()
{
dbg = std::make_shared<Dbg>(false);
c1Inst = C1(dbg);
}
```

Comment: I believe he left the c1Inst to initialize by default constructor(as parametrized C0 don't initialize C1), so he has 2 separate pointers(for C1 initialized with default value), which isn't an undefined behavior. I may be wrong, so I will appreciate explanation :)

For the code posted there, it is true that the pointer to `Dbg` called by `run` in `C0` will call the default constructed one in `C1`, not the one that was passed, and it looks like the passed pointer is useless for this case, but at least it is not undefined behavior.

Comment: But it is initialized in `C0` with `C1 c1Inst;` it is not a pointer, so it will call a default constructor: `C1() { dbg = std::make_shared<Dbg>(false); }`, `c1Inst` dbg pointer will not be null, nor c1Inst will be null, even though we will have two instances of pointer, which seems redundant for this case (maybe it is on purpose in others), I believe it doesn't result in undefined behavior